# Experiment to identify of all the poles from the input output data irrespective of pole zero cancellation?

Tags: pole-zeroplot

The pole zero cancellation reduces the order of the system. As a result we can't identify all the poles from the input output data. Given, input output data, can I devise an experiment such that I can identify all the poles?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You can get exact cancellation in digital systems (Hogenhaur interpolator for instance), but not in analogue systems.

Answer (score 0):

Not if cancellation is perfect.

However, if there is a very slight difference between a pole and its cancelling zero, this produces a 'dipole' (control engineering term, not an antenna!); and a dipole shows up as a long tail on the step response (the step response takes a significant time to reach its steady state). The larger the difference, the larger the tail; the smaller the difference, the smaller, but more persistent is the tail.